# Can't find the id of a button in android

Tags: android, android-button

I've created a button in xml file. But when i try to use it java using `findViewById` it doesn't appear.

Comment: code please ........of activity and layout

Comment: just clean your project from Project->Clean.. on Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 4):

in Activity xml layout add button with id as:

**STEP 1:**

```
 <Button 
 android:id="@+id/btn_id" <--add button id here --> 
 /////.....
 ">
 </Button>
```

**STEP 2:**
After Adding id in Button Layout.Clean project from  **Project->Clean..**

**STEP 3:**
 and In Activity Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.button_view); 
  Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_id);
  //code here...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post you code for your axml file and the code for where you are trying to access the UI element.

Maybe you forgot the "+" or have it in the wrong place:

```
...
android:id="@+id/myuielement
...
```